# Jquery Steps Wizard breaks meteor reactivity

Tags: meteor, jquery-steps

I am using JQuery steps with Meteor and for some reason the steps dont get re-rendered when the data in the page gets updated hence breaking the reactivity.
I have followed the steps as suggested in this post
[JQuery and Reactive Meteor Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160981/jquery-and-reactive-meteor-components)

However the components are appearing twice, appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue.Below is the peice of code that seems to have solved the reactivity issue but there are duplicate components.

```
var temp = this;
Blaze.render(
Template.orderSettings,
temp.$('#reactiveUI').get(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several unsuccessful attempts trying to delete the template using Blaze.remove API, I finally tried to delete the JQuery.Steps rendered component(which has lost reactivity) using simple JQuery API which worked.

```
var reactiveNode = $("#reactiveUI").get(0);
reactiveNode.remove();
```

And then added the same template back to the wizard by calling, implicit call to render with the template name will retain reactivity, my template was updated automatically upon any update to template data, in this case mongo collections.

```
Blaze.render(
Template.orderSettings,
temp.$('#reactiveUII').get(0)
);
```

I have spent several hours close to 20 hrs trying to find a solution or workaround for this issue with JQuery Steps2 wizard.